# Counting frequency of ngrams

Tags: python, parsing, encoding, split, counter

I have split text to subsequent words using ngrams with this Python script:

```
from nltk.util import ngrams

sentence = open('text.txt', "r")
n = 2
sixgrams = ngrams(sentence.read().split(), n)

for grams in sixgrams:
      print (grams)
```

Now I am faced with following two problems.

**1**. My result looks like this

```
('\xd1\x8e\xd0\xbc', '\xd0\xb1\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd0\xb3\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd')
```

It is maybe because text.txt file has Russian Cyrillic characters and encoded in UTF-8. Is there a way to see my result in a human readable format in Python?

**2**. I tried using Collections.Counter to get the each subsequent words combinations' frequency count, and print all ngrams that come up more than 2 times (sorted by value). I tried it for hours cant make it show the way I want.

input example :

```
Diddle  diddle  dumpling  my son Diddle  diddle my son
```

output example:

```
Diddle diddle  2
diddle dumpling 2
dumpling my 1
my son 2
son Diddle 1
Diddle my 1
my son 1
```

output example with limit of 2:

```
Diddle diddle  2
diddle dumpling 2
my son 2
```

Comment: are you using python 2.7?

Comment: It is preferable to use Python 3 for NLP tasks because of Python 3's superior text capabilities :/

Comment: In Python 3 you'd have seen `юм байгаан`  already

Comment: I am using Enthought Canopy, and for some reason for large data Canopy fails.

Comment: 1. --> write your output to a file (utf-8) and open this file with an editor that handles utf-8 well 2. --> Take a look at my complete Answer to your other question [Redirecting the print output to a .txt file in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36172710/redirecting-the-print-output-to-a-txt-file-in-python).

Comment: At least: Python 2 and Python 3 String handling is complete different (print command also)! If you are new to Python, you should use Python 3, it's string handling is quite easier for newbies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For part one of your question, as far as I can see, you are reading from an `UTF-8` encoded file. You can call `decode('utf8')` on the resulting data to decode it. For printing the result, assuming your terminal can handle it, use `encode('utf8')` again to convert it to a readable string.

As for part 2 of your question, I have extended your code and included a `Counter`:

```
from nltk.util import ngrams
import collections

with open("text.txt", "rU") as f:
    sixgrams = ngrams(f.read().decode('utf8').split(), 2)

result = collections.Counter(sixgrams)
print result
with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
    for item, count in sorted(result.iteritems()):
        if count >= 2:
            text = "{} {}".format(" ".join(item).encode('utf8'), count)
            print text
            print >>f, text
```

For your example text file the output is as follows:

```
Counter({('Diddle', 'diddle'): 2, ('my', 'son'): 2, ('dumpling', 'my'): 1, ('son', 'Diddle'): 1, ('diddle', 'dumpling'): 1, ('diddle', 'my'): 1})
Diddle diddle 2
my son 2
```

This also works with a file that contains umlauts:

```
Counter({(u'D\xf6ddle', u'diddle'): 2, (u'my', u'son'): 2, (u'dumpling',u'my'): 1, (u'diddle', u'dumpling'): 1, (u'son', u'D\xf6ddle'): 1, (u'diddle', u'my'): 1})
Döddle diddle 2
my son 2
```

**EDIT:** I added code to save the output to the file `output.txt`.

Comment: as far as I can see the `most-common` function has other rules to decide what to include in the output. As his requirement is everything that comes up more than once in sorted order I think that is the solution. What would you change?

Comment: Ah indeed, I did not notice that the values were sorted.

Comment: It works like a charm. Thank you so much. One last thing, how do you save the result to a .txt file?  I added following code to the end but didn't work        output = open("output.txt", "w")        output.write(result)       output.close()

Comment: Well you cannot simply write an object to a file. You could use the `pickle` module for this, or you could redirect the print output to the file. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: how do I redirect the print output to the file?