# Redirecting the print output to a .txt file in Python

Tags: python, parsing, text

I am complete beginner in Python. I have tried many methods from stackoverflow answers on this question, but neither of them works in my script.
I have this little script to use, however I can not get the huge result to .txt file so I can analyize the data.  How do I redirect the print output to txt file on my computer?

```
from nltk.util import ngrams
import collections

with open("text.txt", "rU") as f:
    sixgrams = ngrams(f.read().decode('utf8').split(), 2)

result = collections.Counter(sixgrams)
print result
for item, count in sorted(result.iteritems()):
    if count >= 2:
        print " ".join(item).encode('utf8'), count
```

Comment: If you're complete beginner to Python and especially since it seems you're doing NLP, I'd recommend you to switch to Python 3 outright!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`print` statement in Python 2.x](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement) support redirection (`>> fileobj`):

```
...
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    print >>f, result
    for item, count in sorted(result.iteritems()):
        if count >= 2:
            print >>f, " ".join(item).encode('utf8'), count
```

In Python 3.x, [`print` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) accepts optional keyword parameter `file`:

```
print("....", file=f)
```

If you do [`from __future__ import print_function`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html) in Python 2.6+, above approach is possible even in Python 2.x.

Answer (score 5):

Just do it on command line: `python script.py > text.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Using a BufferedWriter you can do it like this

```
os = io.BufferedWriter(io.FileIO(pathOut, "wb"))
os.write( result+"\n")
for item, count in sorted(result.iteritems()):
     if count >= 2:
     os.write(" ".join(item).encode('utf8')+ str(count)+"\n")

outs.flush()
outs.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

As Antti mentioned, you should prefer python3 and leave all this annoying
python2 junk behind you. The following script works with python2 and python3.

To read/write files, use `open` function from the [io](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) module, this is
python2/python3 compatible. Allways use the `with` statment to open a resource like a file. The `with` is used to wrap the execution of a block within a  [Python Context Manager](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Context_Managers). File descriptors have context mananger implementend, and will be closed automaticly on leaving the `with` block.

Not depend on python, if you want to read a text-file, you should know the
encoding of this file to read it proper (if you are unsure try `utf-8`
first). Beside, the correct UTF-8 signature is `utf-8` and the mode `U` is
depricated.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8; mode: python -*-

from nltk.util import ngrams
import collections
import io, sys

def main(inFile, outFile):

    with io.open(inFile, encoding="utf-8") as i:
        sixgrams = ngrams(i.read().split(), 2)

    result = collections.Counter(sixgrams)
    templ = "%-10s %s\n"

    with io.open(outFile, "w", encoding="utf-8") as o:

        o.write(templ %  (u"count",  u"words"))
        o.write(templ %  (u"-" * 10, u"-" * 30))

        # Sorting might be expensive. Before sort, filter items you don't want
        # to handle, btw. place *count* in front of the tuple.

        filtered = [ (c, w) for w, c in result.items() if c > 1]
        filtered.sort(reverse=True)

        for count, item in filtered:
            o.write(templ % (count, " ".join(item)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main("text.txt", "out_text.txt"))
```

With the input `text.txt` file:

```
At eight o'clock on Thursday morning and Arthur didn't feel very good 
he missed 100 € on Thursday morning. The Euro symbol of 100 € is here
to test the encoding of non ASCII characters, because encoding errors
do occur only on Thursday morning.
```

I get the following `output_text`:

```
count      words
---------- ------------------------------
3          on Thursday
2          Thursday morning.
2          100 €
```